# Find the length ( furthest) between the nodes in a graph in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

Need help in the graph dataa base ( neo4j)

here is my graph -

**Nodes**

- student(id, title, link)
- class(id, title, link)
- drama (id, title, link)

**Relationships**

- student - LIKE {type: class/drama} - student
- student - DISLIKE {type: class/drama} - student
- student - APPEARED - class
- student - APPEARED - drama

Likeness can be measured for its "length", where each hop through an "Like" relationship is one unit length. Find the ally furthest away from student ID

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (s:Student{id :"studentId"})-[r:like*]->(s1:Student)
WITH s , s1 , COLLECT(SIZE(relationships(r))) as distanceList
WITH s, s1, apoc.coll.sort(distanceList)  as sortedDistanceList
WITH s, s1 , sortedDistanceList[0] as closestDistance ORDER BY closestDistance DESC LIMIT 1 
RETURN s1.id as farthestNodeId
```

First try to find all student nodes connected to given student with variable length. A student can be connected to other student in multiple ways . So, we store the distances of all the paths in distanceList . Then, we can sort the list to get the smallestPath . Longest of the smallest paths is the farthest node . There can be multiple nodes at same fathest distance . If you want to get all of them , you can collect all those student ids into list .